# How to check a variable is class object or not

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Assume a simple class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

.
.
.
m = MyClass
print type(m) # gets: <type 'classobj'>
# if m is classobj, how can i check a variable is class object?
```

My question is: how can i check a variable is a class object?

a simple solution:

```
if str(type(m)) == "<type 'classobj'>":
    # do something
```

But i think there is at least one classic way to check that.

Comment: The code you showed above will not print `<type 'classobj'>` for `type(m)`, because `m` is a new-style class. It will print `<type 'type'>`. You'll only get `<type 'classobj'>` for classic classes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In 2.x, a class object can be be a `type` (new-style classes) or a `classobj` (classic classes). The `type` type is a builtin, but the `classobj` type is not. So, how do you get it? That's what the [`types`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) module is for.

```
isinstance(MyClass, (types.TypeType, types.ClassType))
```

In 3.x, you don't need to worry about classic classes, so:

```
isinstance(MyClass, type)
```

---

Even if you want to compare the types directly, you should never compare *any* objects by their `str`. Compare:

```
>>> class MyClassicClass:
...     pass
>>> str(type(MyClassicClass)) == "<type 'classobj'>"
True
>>> str("<type 'classobj'>") == "<type 'classobj'>"
True
```

You can almost always just compare objects directly:

```
>>> type(MyClassicClass) == types.ClassType
True
>>> "<type 'classobj'>" == types.ClassType
False
```

(And in the incredibly rare cases where you really do need to compare the string representation for some reason, you want the `repr`, not the `str`.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  +1 (more if I could)

Comment: +1. I like Jochen's answer for its simplicity, but this is a good explanation.

Comment: The [`six`](https://six.readthedocs.io) library has a pre-defined value that covers Python 2 or 3. See `class_types`.

Comment: Seems like `types.ClassType` doesn't exist any more (at least in Python 3.10)

Answer (score 43):

Use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass):

```
import inspect
print inspect.isclass(obj)
```

Comment: +1 for inspect module

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that ... (+1)

Comment: I don't know how I forgot this, but this is a better answer than mine (and the equivalents to mine).

Comment: @abarnert -- Yes, but yours explains *how* it all works, which is definitely worth keeping around.

Comment: @abarnert -- It's not about what gets accepted ... As long as the community chooses this one, it's all good I think :).

Comment: all your answers are realy best answer. but just for good explanation, abarnert answer has been accepted.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Python 3.9.16.

Answer (score 8):

A new-style class (derived explicitly from `object` as in your example, or implicitly in Python 3) is not of type `classobj`. Only old-style classes are `classobj`s. So for your example class as written, you could simply check to see if `MyClass` is an instance of `type`, as all new-style classes are:

```
isinstance(MyClass, type)
```

Because all new-style classes are derived from `object` you can also do:

```
issubclass(MyClass, object)
```

I would advise against:

```
type(MyClass) == type
```

This will fail if the type of a class is not `type`, but a metaclass. Although there may be use cases for that, of course.

If you really need to see if you've got an old-style class, you can import the `types` module and use `types.ClassType`, or just declare an old-style class and see if the class you're testing is of the same type:

```
class OldStyleClass:
   pass
OldStyleClass = type(OldStyleClass)

isinstance(MyClass, OldStyleClass)
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> class A(object):
...    pass
>>> isinstance(A, type)
True

>>> isinstance("asd", type)
False
```

But works only for classes inherited from object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the next is working (if you want to determine how to print the object):

```
def is_class(o):
    return hasattr(o, '__dict__')
```

Comment: most of objects including classes, has this attribute

Comment: @pylover Excuse me, I answered to another question: "How to determine if a variable is a class instance". I'm agree with you. But could you give an example of objects which are not classes and have this attribute?

Comment: No, the question is `How to check a variable is class **OBJECT** or not`, not INSTANCE

Comment: Your method always return true for either class or instance

Comment: @pylover `i = int(5)` is an `object`, because `issubclass(int, object)` is `True`, but the method returns `False` for ints because `int` is not a real user-defined class. so. its not an instance of a real class.

Comment: you don't get the question well as well.